# What is the maximum level a character can reach in Borderlands?

Tags: borderlands

What is the **maximum level** that a character can reach in Borderlands for PC without any of the DLC installed, and with all of the DLC installed?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have the Xbox version, but the maximum level without DLC should be **58**. With "The Secret Armory of General Knoxx" the maximum is **69** (it goes to eleven, har har).

"The Zombie Island of Dr. Ned" doesn't affect the maximum level. "Mad Moxxi's Underdome Riot" doesn't either, but it does provide 2 extra skill points you only normally get by ranking up. One for beating the "lesser challenge" (only 5 rounds) in each of the 3 stadiums during playthrough #1, and the other for doing the same in playthrough #2.

The level cap for all characters was increased by 8 with the release of patch 1.4.1. This makes a total of **69** skill points to earn, though the four gained from DLC's 2 and 4 will still require those add-ons (as they are mission rewards). ([source](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Experience_Points))

Comment: Does this answer need to be updated for Claptrap's Robot Revolution?

Comment: I changed the max level counts, it was very confusing that the first numbers listed are 50 and 61, which haven't been correct for a very long time.

Answer (score 11):

Gearbox has announced at PAX that they are releasing a free update to increase the max level cap by 8 levels and rebalance the vanilla game to accommodate for the increase. It is not necessary to own any of the previous DLC in order to take advantage of the level cap raise.  So if you do not own the *The Secret Armory of General Knoxx* DLC, your max level cap will be **58**, and if you do, the max level will be **69**. 2 skill points will also be available in the upcoming *Claptrap's New Robot Revolution* DLC.

[Source](http://www.joystiq.com/2010/09/05/free-borderlands-update-will-raise-level-cap-rebalance-main-gam/)

Answer (score 0):

61 currently, with the latest DLC. 50 without DLCs. 69 soon in an october patch.

Answer (score -3):

Max level is **50**.